# Remove default value in printUsage() method. [args4j library]

Tags: java, default-value, args4j

How to get rid of "(default:value)" when using printUsage() method?
[Image](http://oi61.tinypic.com/mj8i8p.jpg)

I tried to look at the source code of args4j library and searched for printUsage() method in CmdLineParser Class but didn't find anything there. ([link](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/args4j/args4j/2.0.29&path=/Source%20Packages/main.java.org.kohsuke.args4j/NamedOptionDef.java))
The problem appears only with boolean type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems late, but maybe this answer still helps someone:

You need to overwrite the default BooleanOptionHandler with your own OptionHandler. First, create a class (in a separate file, because of reflection calls) like this:

```
public class HelpOptionHandler extends BooleanOptionHandler {
    public HelpOptionHandler(CmdLineParser parser, OptionDef option, Setter<Boolean> setter) {
        super(parser, option, setter);
    }
    public String printDefaultValue() {
         return null;  // this prevents the default value to be printed in usage info
    }
}
```

Then, register this option handler in your help annotation like this:

```
@Option(name = "-h", aliases = "-help", help = true, usage = "print this message", 
        handler = jondos.vodafone.helper.HelpOptionHandler.class)
protected boolean help;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ParserProperties properties = ParserProperties.defaults();
properties.withOptionSorter(null); // Do not sort cmdLine options
properties.withShowDefaults(false); // Do not print defaults
CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(this, properties);
```